# Relational query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have tree tables: "CLient", "Route" and "RelCliRoute".

The table "RelCliRoute" saves the relation between clients and routes, saving the client id in a field called IdCli and also saving the id of the route in another field called IdRoute, so that a client may belong to a route.

I need to create a query that brings me the number of clients per route and also the name of such route, this to be able to make a graph with the different routes and how many clients own each route has

this is my client model:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = "IdCli"

  has_many :relcliroutes, class_name: "Relcliroute", foreign_key: "IdCli"


end
```

my Relcliroute model:

```
class Relcliroute < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = "Id"
  belongs_to :client, class_name:"Client", foreign_key: "IdCli"
  belongs_to :route, class_name:"Route", foreign_key: "IdRoute"
end
```

my route model:

```
class Route < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = "IdRoute"

  has_many :relcliroutes, class_name: "Relcliroute", foreign_key: "IdRoute"

end
```

Comment: What have you done so far? Show your code and we may help you.

Comment: I edited your question and translated your Portuguese title to English, the official language of SO. Please, use only English when writing here.

Comment: If you don't fell comfortable with English, you may use this http://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @EddeAlmeida thats the thing I dont know how to do this type of query, because this query should bring me all the routes that have a client through the table "RelCliRoute", and also must show me how many clients has each route and the name of the route

Comment: How about your models? Have you set these relations there? Would you mind to post the Client and Route models?

Comment: @EddeAlmeida models posted:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to make `has_many :through` associations for Client and Route

```
# client model
has_many :routes, through: :relcliroutes, source: :route

# route model
has_many :clients, through: :relcliroutes, source: :client
```

Then you can use [Rails association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) methods to access the clients for a route.

```
route = Route.first
clients = route.clients
number_of_clients = clients.count
client_names = client.pluck :name
```

However I'm not sure why you're setting a custom primary key.

Comment: I think this is a legacy table and then he is setting the primary key. I would rather change the table to keep Rails conventions.